# Apply PCA and keep a percentage of the total variance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, pca

I want to perform Principal Component Analysis on a particular dataset and then feed the principal components to a `LogisticRegression` classifier.

Specifically, I want to apply `PCA` and keep the 90% of the total variance, using the function `computePrincipalComponentsAndExplainedVariance`.

Here's the code for reading the dataset:

```
// Load the data
val text = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("dataset.data")        
val data = text.map(line => line.split(',').map(_.toDouble))  
// Separate to label and features
val dataLP = data.map(t => (t(57), Vectors.dense(t.take(57))))
```

I am not quite sure how to perform PCA so that the 90% of the total variance is maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the function `computePrincipalComponentsAndExplainedVariance` the return value will be a matrix as well as a vector with values indicating the variance explained for each principal component. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.html#computePrincipalComponentsAndExplainedVariance(int)):

> Returns: a matrix of size n-by-k, whose columns are principal components, and a vector of values which indicate how much variance each principal component explains

By using a large enough k as input, you can simply sum up the numbers in the vector until it's 90% or above, and then use that many columns from the matrix.